# How to insert HTML/JavaScript form into WordPress page?

Tags: plugins, php, javascript, forms, html

I am trying to insert a small form into a WordPress page that does a minor calculation based on user input and returns an answer. Initially I tried copying the entire thing (HTML and JS (in a `<script>` tag) in the text editor), which displayed the HTML form fine, but trying to run the JS didn't work.

The JS looks like this:

```
function calculateX(){
    var inputA, inputB, total;
    inputA = document.form.inputA.value;
    inputB = document.form.inputB.value;
    total = inputA + inputB * 10;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = parseInt(total);
}
```

The HTML form looks like this:

```
<form name="form">
    InputA: <input type="text" name="inputA" /><br />
    InputB: <input type="text" name="inputB" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateX()" /><br />
    Your result is: <b><span id="result"></span></b>
</form>
```

I later tried creating a plugin that would run the JS while only inserting the above HTML in the page text editor while adding the JS to the `calculate.js` file. It looked like this:

```
 <?php
 /*
 Plugin Name: Calculate
 */
 function calculate() {
      wp_register_script('calculate', plugins_url('/js/calculate.js'), __FILE__), array('jquery'), false);
      wp_enqueue_script('calculate', plugins_url('/js/calculate.js'), __FILE__);
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'calculate');
 ?>
```

However, neither solution works. I'm pretty new to JavaScript and this is the first time I've attempted to implement a form like this in WordPress by myself, so I'm not entirely sure where it goes wrong.

The form is displayed perfectly fine, but when clicking the 'Calculate' button it does nothing.

**EDIT: See @RRikesh' comments below on the process of fixing this. The code as it stands above works for me now.**

Comment: This question is not much about WordPress. Also: You didn't give the function a name in the `wp_enqueue_script` hook and you spelled `getElementById` wrong.

Comment: @RRikesh - apologies. it seems I rushed things when I wrote the description. I've fixed the errors in the post now. My actual code has a function name for the `wp_enqueue_script` and `getElementById` spelled correctly. The problem is still present.

Comment: Your function can't be called `calculateY` when the callback is `calculate`. Both should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of issues:

## 1. WordPress part:

Your function is hooked to [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) and should be like this:

```
function wpse238953_calculate() {
      wp_enqueue_script('calculate', plugins_url('/js/calculate.js'), __FILE__), array('jquery'), false);
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse238953_calculate');
```

Note the different spellings between [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) and [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

## 2. The HTML/JS part:

Let's add some `id` to the two input fields so that it's easier to target them

```
<form name="form">
    InputA: <input type="text" id="inputA" name="inputA" /><br />
    InputB: <input type="text" id="inputB" name="inputB" /><br />
    <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate" /><br />
    Your result is: <b><span id="result"></span></b>
</form>
```

Then rewrite your JS and use some jQuery(since you added it as a dependency):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    'use strict';
  $('#calculate').mousedown(function(){
    var valueA = parseFloat( $('#inputA').val(), 10 ),
        valueB = parseFloat( $('#inputB').val(), 10 ),
        total = ( valueA + valueB ) * 10;
    
    $('#result').text( total );
  });
});
```

Read about:

- http://api.jquery.com/text/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat
- https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery:

First debug and check if the function is getting called. Try `alert()` in your JS function.

```
<form name="form">
    InputA: <input type="text" class="inputA" name="inputA" /><br />
    InputB: <input type="text" class="inputB" name="inputB" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateX()" /><br />
    Your result is: <b><span id="result"></span></b>
</form>

function calculateX(){
    total = jQuery('inputA').val() + jQuery('inputA').val();
    jQuery('#result').html(total);
}
```

Comment: I should've done debugging right away - it appears that the function is not being called as I see no pop-up from adding `alert()`. So presumably the error is in the plugin php, right?

Comment: In that case first check JS is en-queued properly, as in it appears in your html.